# My Samsung Galaxy S2 keeps saying not registered on network when I try to phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, network-signal, mobile-network

My Samsung Galaxy  S2 keeps saying not registered on network when I try to phone also a no entry sign where the signal bars should be keeps randomly appearing.

Does anyone know how to fix it or whats happening?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may need to reset your APN settings, Your phone will be slightly different than mine, I'm using a Nexus 4.  Try locating the following:

Settings -> Wireless & Networks -> Mobile Networks -> Access Point Names -> and from there locate the "Reset to default" option.

If that doesn't work, you can backup your device, and factory reset it.

Comment: I have got to access point names but can not find a reset to default option.

Comment: i did have my phone unlocked from orange so i could put my vodafone sim in i dont know if that would effect it? but that was months ago and the phone has worked fine untill now. @Michael

Comment: Try looking here, Menu > Settings > Wireless & Network > Mobile Network > Access Point Names > then press Menu, and look for the reset option.

Comment: ok found i have found it and reset it but it still says not registered on network, @michael

Comment: In that case I would perform a factory reset

Comment: i have prefromed a factory reset and i am still expierencing the same problem @michael

Comment: Experiencing a similar issue at the moment. Any known solution?